# Does an AD terminate by issuing new one?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, airworthiness-directive

When an AD superseded by a new one, Does the operator still retain the instruction of superseded AD even though the AD include repetitive action?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking. Are you asking if a new version of an AD always supersedes any previous versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a typical US AD where as I mentioned in a previous post, they don't issue "revisions", like AD 2019-12, AD 2019-12 Rev A, Rev B, Rev C etc.   If the AD is basically the same but has some internal change, the FAA will not issue a "Rev A".  They will issue a superceding AD with a new number that is the same as the old one except for various changes which will be spelled out.  So AD 2019-23 will be replaced by AD 2019-32, which supercedes 2019-23, instead of 2010-23 Rev A, as would be done in Canada or elsewhere.

That language tells you that the new AD is issued with administrative changes and that the compliance requirements are the same as the superceded AD, including any repetitive instruction.  In fact the new AD should have all the compliance requirements of the old one included in it.

Comment: Mr. John K, thank you so much for helping, then we must close the status of the old rev. AD(repetitive) for applicable A/C and add new replacement AD to the list and comply it.

Comment: Yes the old one is superceded so it is no longer in effect.

Comment: But  we've bought an A/C and I've seen an AD is open in the AD status that complied with in the previous operator, now that AD is due, such as EASA AD No.2011-0006 that superseded by 2014-0018R1,  Do I take  into account AD 2011-0006 for nearest maintenance check or I ignore it (those ADs are presented in status and 2011-000 6not closed)

Comment: The difference between 0006 and 0018 is the requirement for placards with Skydrol resistant glue.  If the airplane was compliant with 0006, the inspection and swap to the one-weld accumulator should have been done and you're covered by the statement "unless accomplished previously" in 0018.  However 0018 does include new placards so you still have to swap out the placard required by 0006 with the better one under 0018.  If 0006 was never complied with at all, then it's like it never existed and just comply with 0018.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an example of an AD that supersedes an older one. In this case the FAA decided that the requirement that an inspection be performed by an A&P was not necessary and that pilots were smart enough to check whether their fuel selector was labelled correctly. If you find the link to the old one on [FAA website](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAD.nsf/Frameset?OpenPage), it will show that it has been superseded. But you can still find the old pdf without any indication that it has been cancelled. If you are looking for a particluar AD, make sure you search in the current ADs section of their website. The naming convention differs from the Advisory Circular, FAA Order, and FAA publication method where the old ones are still on the website and the newest one has the highest letter, e.g. AC 61-65E, AC 61-98D, FAA Order JO 7400.9Z.

> We are superseding Airworthiness Directive (AD) 2018-02-05 for certain
>   Piper Aircraft, Inc. Models PA-28-140, PA-28-150, PA-28-151,
>   PA-28-160, PA-28-161, PA-28-180, PA- 28-181, PA-28-236, PA-28-201T,
>   PA-28R-180, PA-28R-200, PA-28R-201, PA-28R-201T, PA- 28RT-201, and
>   PA-28RT-201T airplanes. AD 2018-02-05 required inspecting the fuel
>   tank selector cover to verify the left and right fuel tank selector
>   placards are located at the proper positions and replacing those that
>   are improperly located with new placards. This AD addresses the same
>   unsafe condition and requires the same actions as AD 2018-02-05, but
>   changes the inspection of the fuel tank selector cover to a preflight
>   check and allows for various fuel selector clocking configurations.